# FetchAPI . Im getting an empty string from my own express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

I've set up an express.js server on 4000 port. getting a request and sending a plain text string.

```
let express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 4000;

app.listen(port, () => { console.log(`SERVER is running on port ${port}`)});

app.use(express.text());

app.get("/", (req,res) =>{
   console.log("Get from /");
   res.send("Hello world");
});
```

and i'am trying to fetch a string "Hello world"using fetchApi.

```
window.onload = ()=>{
  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:4000/", {
      method: "GET",
      mode: "no-cors"
  }).then(res=>{
      return res.text();
  }).then( text => {
      console.log(text);
  });
};
```

i am getting an empty string in console but when i open network sent requests i see the message in network response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> ```
>  mode: "no-cors"
> ```

Which means "I am not going to do anything that requires the server to grant permission with CORS so don't fill the console with errors if I don't have that permission".

Since reading a response cross-origin **requires permission** from CORS and you said you didn't *want* permission, you get an empty string back when you try to read the response.

If you want to read the response, you need CORS, so take the `mode` config out.

Comment: This helps me 
```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:63343");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

Comment: @Alexander — Use the `cors` module from NPM instead of rolling your own. Don't allow random request headers you don't need. `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` should never be on a request. `Origin` doesn't need permission. `X-Requested-With` is an ugly hack and the request should use `Accept` instead. `Content-Type` shouldn't exist on a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **the last version of Express** so try this code and you don't need express.text():

```
 const express = require("express");
 const app = express();
 const port = 4000;
 app.listen(port, () => { console.log(`SERVER is running on port ${port}`)}); 
 app.get("/", (req,res) =>{ console.log("Get from /"); res.send("Hello world") });
```

Then :

```
window.onload = ()=>{ fetch("http://127.0.0.1:4000/", { method: "GET"}).then(res=>{ return res }).then( text => { console.log(text); }); };
```